# A winform with sections that can be resized, and auto-resize

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I am creating a C# winform (not asp.net) with two sections.
The left section is a sort of toolbar, where the user will enter a few images to be displayed.
The right section will display the information, the images.

Images can be any size, but the toolbar will almost always be the same size.

I wanted these two sections to be seperate, aka a divider between them, that I can drag about.
As well, any time an image is chosen, the right screen will resize, or at least resize and give me a scrollbar.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: is the UI in asp.net or winforms?

Comment: First make it clear is it a Web or Win app.... Or if it is.. please tell us the way, you prepared the cocktail....

Comment: Windows app, winforms. Edited into the message, didn't realize I had to clarify, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer). You will need to set the [FixedPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.fixedpanel%28VS.100%29.aspx) property to the panel you want to remain the same size.